# Website image not being displayed CSS

Tags: html, css, image, web

I have been doing a website, and i have a problem because the image does not want to be displayed on screen. However, I have checked the code multiple times and it all seems correct! And the image is also located within the same folder of the php file. I really don't know why this is happening. Could you please help me figure it out?
Thank you!

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body{
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', 'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
}
.container {
    width: 1000px;
}
.div1 {
    background-image: url("pic1.jpg");
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Restaurant</h1>

<div class="container">
<div class="div1">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the image located?

Comment: Your div has no height. By default divs are block elements and take up the full width of their container, but without any content or height being set they have none.

Comment: @Matt Cremeens it is in the same folder of the php file.. I have checked multiple times

Comment: Using Chrome or Firefox check your Developer Tools and see whether `pic1.img` is successfully being retrieved by the browser.  i.e., if it is a `200` then the image is succesful and your problem is your css/html.  If it is a `400` or `500` error, then the image isn't able to be retrieved.

Comment: @rrauenza the image is being successfully retrieved because it worked well when i used the <img> tag instead. However, I can't use the <img> tag because I need to use <div> 's as i have to add multiple images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is correct. The only thing you need to do is adding content to your div, like

```
<div class="div1"><h2>Here is another caption</h2></div>
```

In the area of h2 there will be your specified background picture.

[image: RESULT]

Comment: I tried what you said, and it worked. But I got multiple repetitions of the same image. The only problem is that I only want one whole image without any repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
.div1 {
height: 610px;
width: 100%;
background: url("https://images-contests.99static.com/FtR2bRSgATkGUAOWom3RW3FznWQ=/fit-in/900x675/99designs-contests-attachments/0/384/attachment_384160");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If you're going to use a background image in a div with no other content to give it dimensions, you need to specify that div's height and width so the image will show. https://jsfiddle.net/g5gL1ue7/